# Averaging shapes (boundary points) of arbitrary objects

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, shapes

I have few images (contours) of an object. However, I would like to average these shapes and use the averaged shape of the object for further shape analysis.

Example:

[image: Averaged shape]

In the above image, I have stacked the contour to illustrate my example.

I have implemented the first two steps of the algorithm below:

1) Find centroid of both these object shape

2) Align the centers

3) Interpolate the object shape

Since, I am not representing the shapes using some parametric/analytic equation, how can I get the interpolated object shape (i.e. third step)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by averaging the shapes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have a parametric form for your shape, you can:

- For each shape, create a signed distance field that is positive inside the boundary and negative outside (or vice-versa). This can be based on (e.g.) a [distance transform](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/distance.htm) and is evaluated at every pixel.
- Compute the average of the signed distance fields
- Compute the interpolated shape from the zero-crossing of the averaged field

I think this paper describes a similar method (though probably more sophisticated): "Shape-based interpolation using a chamfer distance" http://rd.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0033762 , but I don't have journal access at my current location to check.

Comment: Thanks. I have implemented it using OpenCV C++ and it worked perfect. I used cv::pointPolygonTest function which returns the signed distance. However, it is taking some finite time for computation. I have to do this for 10,000s of images. So can you suggest more efficient method for computing signed distance?

Comment: I'm not too knowledgeable about OpenCV, however it sounds like you're manually iterating over each pixel, which is always slow. I would try something like getting the [distance transform](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/miscellaneous_image_transformations.html) to give you an unsigned value, then somehow negate the distance based on a flood-fill. It's "easy" in Matlab or Numpy, but I'm not sure about OpenCV. You might be better off with a separate question if you're having issues :)